# jquery link with MySQL - full code

Tags: jquery

I am stuck, my code should manage contacts and be able to alter them.

I would like to click to the Name1, Name2, Name3 and be able to see on the right hand side and be able to submit/save it in my SQL DB.

```
<?php 
include("db_con1.php"); 

// left side people list
$peoplelist='SELECT contact_first, contact_sur, contact_mobil FROM contactmain WHERE status=1';
$queryl = $pdo->prepare($peoplelist);
$queryl->execute();
?>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">

<html>
<head>
  <title>Email sending program</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/adminolok.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/menu.css">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
  <script>
  $('leftnavigation a.names').click(
    var thisId = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.midtop input').val( $(this).html() + $(this).attr('id'); );
  </script>
</head>

<body>
<?php include("menu.php"); ?>

<div id="leftnavigation">
<ul>
<?php foreach ($queryl as $i => $rowl) { ?>
<li >
  <a href="#" class="names" id="<?php echo $i; ?>">
    <span class="name">
     <?php echo $rowl['contact_first'].' <strong>'.$rowl['contact_sur'].'</strong>'; ?>
    </span>
    <br />
    <span class="mobil"><?php echo $rowl['contact_mobil'];?></span>
  </a>
<?php  }?>
</li>
</ul>
</div>


<div id="midtop">
 Change your name: <input type="text" name="name" />

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

As I am getting more and more help I feel that I will be... but it is still full of bug as it doesn't work yet.  Any help would be really appreciated.

Made some alteration as I've been taught to do so:)))) thanks for that

Comment: Your question does not make sense.  What do you mean by, `I am stack with my code to pass the info from left to right`.  What does this have to do with mySQL?

Comment: sorry for my English hope this version make more sense:)

Comment: You should replace $('.midtop input').val( $(this).html() with $(this).attr('id'); ); with $('.midtop input').val( $(this).html() + $(this).attr('id'); );

Comment: @madc: thanks for your kind help. I keep trying but it still doesn't give any result yet. Any other though?

Comment: Jip. Try changing leftnavigation to #leftnavigation

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like this:

```
$('label').click(function(){
  $('.right input').val( $(this).html(); );
});
```

Comment: thanks for helping. So where do I need to insert this in the code?

Comment: I have changed the label's attributes now each label individual how could I pass the info to the <input>. Sorry for asking to much but I would like to learn it:)

Comment: And, yeah, it yould replace your ???. To get the value of the for-attribute, i would say, you have to repace $(this).html() with $(this).attr('for').

Comment: am I getting closer to the solution? (unfortunately still doesn't work yet)

Answer (score 0):

You can align your list horizontally using CSS:

```
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Check the **[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/arnley/rULSn/)**

Comment: thanks very much for your answer. I have 3000 names in my contact list, so I would stay vertical, but it is a good hint!